Cannot run API (azure Reservations Details) with Powershell
I cannot run PS command Invoke-AzRestMethod with Reservations Details API
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/reservations-details/list-by-reservation-order-and-reservation?view=rest-consumption-2024-08-01&tabs=HTTP)
It works when running as "Try it" on its API page but get error with PowerShell 5.1 and 7
Invoke-AzRestMethod -Method GET -Path "/providers/Microsoft.Capacity/reservationorders/$reservationOrderId/reservations/$ReservationId/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/reservationDetails?$filter=properties/usageDate ge 2024-09-12 AND properties/usageDate le 2024-09-12&api-version=2024-08-01"

**Replace $reservationOrderId and $ReservationId with Reservation ID and Reservation order ID in Reservation
Error

"Bad Request. The argument 'queryOptionName' is null or empty"


I tried in Windows PS, PS 5.1 and PS 7 with same error.

The documentation states that the current API version is 2023-03-01 - does it make a difference if you try with ...&api-version=2023-03-01 instead of ...&api-version=2024-08-01?

"&api-version=2024-08-01" is correct. The issue is $filter not being interpreted as string, which is pointed out in below answer, thanks.

The API call is correct, the issue is that $filter is being interpreted as a PowerShell variable instead of a literal string. You need to use a backtick ` to escape the dollar sign so PowerShell interprets it as a literal string. See double-quoted-strings for more information.
".../Microsoft.Consumption/reservationDetails?`$filter=properties/usageDate..."
#                                             ^ backtick here to escape
#                                               the variable expansion

Another alternative you can use is a single-quote string and insert the $reservationOrderId and $ReservationId with the format operator -f:
$uri = '/providers/Microsoft.Capacity/reservationorders/{0}/reservations/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/reservationDetails?$filter=properties/usageDate ge 2024-09-12 AND properties/usageDate le 2024-09-12&api-version=2024-08-01' -f $reservationOrderId, $ReservationId
Invoke-AzRestMethod -Method GET -Path $uri


Yes, that works great!
Thank you very much for your help! :)
